# Middle mouse button macros don't work

Tags: button, browser, tabs, mouse, autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotKey, and I'm trying to make a macro that will close a browser window that's on a tabbed page. I'm using Pale Moon (a Firefox-type browser) on Windows 7 Home Edition for x64.

I'd like to close the tab window by holding down the right mouse button, then clicking the mouse wheel. I've tried a couple of scripts I downloaded (they work by just clicking the middle mouse button), but they don't do anything; the whole browser just gets minimized (I believe that's the default behavior for the mouse wheel).

The scripts reside on my desktop. Maybe they don't work because they're not made functional, although I right-clicked them and selected Run before I tried them.

Here's one of the scripts that doesn't work:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

MButton::
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, x, y, WinUnderMouseID

    ;Get y position relative to the bottom of the screen.
    yBottom := A_ScreenHeight - y

    ; close tab in active window
    if (yBottom <= 40)
    {


        IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaUIWindowClass
        {
        Send ^w
        return
        } else IfWinActive, ahk_class IEFrame
        {
        Send ^w
        }


    ; else send normal middle click
    } else {
        If GetKeyState("MButton") { ;The middle button is physically down
            MouseClick, Middle,,,0,D        ;middle button down
            KeyWait, MButton                ;to allow dragging
            MouseClick, Middle,,,,0,U       ;release middle button up
        } Else {
            MouseClick, Middle,,
        }

     }

return
```

Answer (score 1):

For practical reasons (keep the menu function of the right button), I would suggest to reverse the order. Press the middle button first, then add the right button press.

```
MButton & RButton::
Send, ^{F4}
return
```